# Adding Own Controller to arduino platform

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, firmware, arduino-ide

Previously  I am using arduino Uno for programming.Next version of arduino board with no pins avialble is Arduino mega2560/1280.Product wise good. BUt if i wanted to develop my own controller With above IC. Price of IC itself takes 1000Rs from Element 14 & 500 Rs locally in market.

I found there some controller with More no Of pins , with better flash /program memory, More analog IOs With Low cost

[Atmega 644](http://www.instructables.com/id/ATmega-644-ArduinoEvaluationboard/)

Others:ATMEGA32A-PU Or ATMEGA32A-APU

I wanted simlar kind OF ic to be added on arduino Platform & develop my own development board compatiable with  Arduino IDe.

If anyone Have IDEa Please help me out How can i Add own controller Here.What are File should be included in Arduino core library?? What are alternation should be made. Your help will be appreciable to develop COntroller.

Also Working Library like wire,GSM,GPRS,Softwareserial,MODBUS

Basic: analog, digital, serial,Blink

Comment: I'm not going to put an answer right now because that is a HUGE question and I can't spare the time. You will need to be able to edit all the core libraries which are written in c and are open source. You can use the hardware designs (open source) as reference. Arduino takes the avr-c software layer and adds a tinker friendly later above it. You will need to rewrite the core libraries to interact with your new chip using the reference is the datasheets from atmel. These are typically very reader friendly

Comment: Such boards exist. Search the Arduino forums. Or look at [So you want to make an Arduino](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Policy)